# Data not showing after selecting the picklist value in lightning

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I have a picklist value account and contact when i select account or contact it will not showing me the data table of account or contact

HTML

```
<template>
   <div class="slds-form-element">
        <label class="slds-form-element__label">
            <template if:true={isAttributeRequired}>
                <abbr title="required">*</abbr>
            </template>
            <span class="">Choose an Option</span>
        </label>
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <div class="slds-select_container">
                <select class="slds-select"
                        name = "optionSelect"
                        onchange={selectionChangeHandler}
                        disabled={isPicklistDisabled}
                        required={isAttributeRequired}>
                    <option value="Select">Select</option>
                    <option value="Account">Account</option>
                    <option value="Contact">Contact</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <lightning-button variant="success" 
                              label="Proceed" 
                              title="Proceed" 
                              onclick={selectionChangeHandler} 
                              class="slds-m-left_x-small">
            </lightning-button>
    
        </div>
        <template if:true={accList}>
            <h2> Account Datatable</h2>
            <lightning-datatable data={accList} 
                                 columns={acc_Columns} 
                                 key-field="Id">
            </lightning-datatable>
        </template>
        <template if:true={conList}>
            <h2> Contact Datatable</h2>
            <lightning-datatable data={conList} 
                                 columns={con_Columns}       
                                 key-field="Id">
            </lightning-datatable>
        </template>
        <template if:true={error}>
            {error}
        </template>
    </div>
</template>
```

JS

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
/* eslint-disable no-alert */
/* eslint-disable vars-on-top */
import {​​​​​​​ LightningElement, track, wire }​​​​​​​ from 'lwc';
import getAccounts from '@salesforce/apex/AccountController.getAccounts';
import getContacts from '@salesforce/apex/AccountController.getContacts';

export default class ListView extends LightningElement {​​​​​​​
        @track acc_Columns=[
                {​​​​​​​
        label: 'Id',
        fieldName: 'Id',
        type: 'text',
        sortable: true
    }​​​​​​​,
            {​​​​​​​
        label: 'Account name',
        fieldName: 'Name',
        type: 'text',
        sortable: true
    }​​​​​​​
       ];
        @track con_Columns=[
                {​​​​​​​
        label: 'Id',
        fieldName: 'Id',
        type: 'text',
        sortable: true
    }​​​​​​​,
            {​​​​​​​
        label: 'Contact name',
        fieldName: 'Name',
        type: 'text',
        sortable: true
    }​​​​​​​,
                {​​​​​​​
        label: 'Email',
        fieldName: 'Email',
        type: 'text',
        sortable: true
    }​​​​​​​
       ];
        // @track selectedOption;
        @track error;
    @track accList ;
        @track conList ;
        @track selectedOption;
        //@track field = event.target.name;
        selectionChangeHandler(event) {​​​​​​​
                const field = event.target.name;
   if (field === 'optionSelect') {​​​​​​​
        this.selectedOption = event.target.value;
            alert("you have selected : "+this.selectedOption);
             this.getAccounts();
}​​​​​​​
        }​​​​​​​
    @wire(getAccounts)
    wiredAccounts({​​​​​​​
        error,
        data
    }​​​​​​​) {​​​​​​​
        if (data) {​​​​​​​
                        if(this.selectedOption ==='Account'){​​​​​​​
            this.accList = data;
                        const columns= this.acc_Columns;
                        }​​​​​​​
        }​​​​​​​ else if (error) {​​​​​​​
            this.error = error;
        }​​​​​​​
    }​​​​​​​
        @wire(getContacts)
    wiredContacts({​​​​​​​
        error,
        data
    }​​​​​​​) {​​​​​​​
        if (data) {​​​​​​​
                        if(this.selectedOption ==='Contact'){​​​​​​​
            this.conList = data;
                        const columns= this.con_Columns;
                        }​​​​​​​
        }​​​​​​​ else if (error) {​​​​​​​
            this.error = error;
        }​​​​​​​
    }​​​​​​​     
}​​​​​​​
```

APEX

```
public with sharing class AccountController {​​​​​​​​
    public static List<Account> getAllActiveAccounts() {​​​​​​​​
    return [SELECT Id,Name,Active__c FROM Account WHERE Active__c = 'Yes'];
  }​​​​​​​​
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable =true)
  public static List<Account> getAccounts(){​​​​​​​​
  return [Select Id, Name, Type, Rating,
                Phone, Website, AnnualRevenue FROM Account Order By Name];
  }​​​​​​​​


  @AuraEnabled(cacheable =true)
  public static List<Contact> getContacts(){​​​​​​​​
  return [Select Id, Name, Email FROM Contact Order By Name];
  }​​​​​​​​
}​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your code and I found some minor mistakes in your code. That's why you are not getting the data. I have modified the code for you.

```
------------------------HTML-----------------------------------
<template>
  <div class="slds-form-element">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label">
      <template if:true={isAttributeRequired}>
        <abbr title="required">*</abbr>
      </template>
      <span class="">Choose an Option</span>
    </label>
    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
      <div class="slds-select_container">
        <select class="slds-select" name="optionSelect" onchange={selectionChangeHandler} disabled={isPicklistDisabled}
          required={isAttributeRequired}>
          <option value="Select">Select</option>
          <option value="Account">Account</option>
          <option value="Contact">Contact</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <lightning-button variant="success" label="Proceed" title="Proceed" onclick={proceedHandler}
        class="slds-m-left_x-small">
      </lightning-button>

    </div>

      <template if:true={accList}>
        <h2> Account Datatable</h2>
        <lightning-datatable data={accList1} columns={columns} key-field="Id">
        </lightning-datatable>
      </template>
      <template if:true={conList}>
        <h2> Contact Datatable</h2>
        <lightning-datatable data={conList1} columns={columns} key-field="Id">
        </lightning-datatable>
      </template>

    <template if:true={error}>
      {error}
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

--------------------------------------JS---------------------------------------

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
/* eslint-disable no-alert */
/* eslint-disable vars-on-top */
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import getAccounts from '@salesforce/apex/AccountController.getAccounts';
import getContacts from '@salesforce/apex/AccountController.getContacts';

export default class ListView extends LightningElement {
  acc_Columns = [
    {
      label: 'Id',
      fieldName: 'Id',
      type: 'text',
      sortable: true
    },
    {
      label: 'Account name',
      fieldName: 'Name',
      type: 'text',
      sortable: true
    }
  ];
  con_Columns = [
    {
      label: 'Id',
      fieldName: 'Id',
      type: 'text',
      sortable: true
    },
    {
      label: 'Contact name',
      fieldName: 'Name',
      type: 'text',
      sortable: true
    },
    {
      label: 'Email',
      fieldName: 'Email',
      type: 'text',
      sortable: true
    }
  ];
  // @track selectedOption;
  error;
  accList = false;
  accList1;
  conList = false;
  conList1;
  selectedOption;
  columns;
  //@track field = event.target.name;
  selectionChangeHandler(event) {
    const field = event.target.name;
    if (field === 'optionSelect') {
      this.selectedOption = event.target.value;
      alert("you have selected : " + this.selectedOption);
      
    }
  }

  proceedHandler(){
    if (this.selectedOption === 'Account') {
      this.accList = true;
      this.getAcc();
      this.conList = false;
    }
    if (this.selectedOption === 'Contact') {
      this.conList = true;
      this.getCon();
      this.accList = false;
    }
    if (this.selectedOption === 'Select') {
      this.accList = false;
      this.conList = false;
    }
  }

  getAcc() {
    getAccounts()
      .then(result => {
        this.accList1 = result;
        this.columns = this.acc_Columns;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.error = error;
      })
  }
  getCon() {
    getContacts()
      .then(result => {
        this.conList1 = result;
        this.columns = this.con_Columns;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.error = error;
      });
  }
}
```

Hope this explanation will resolve your query.

Comment: Please include an explanation in your answer, not just code. Please do not use sign-offs or ask for "best answer", which does not exist here. See [answer].